# How different programming languages handle division by 0?

Tags: division, divide-by-zero

Perhaps this is the wrong sort of question to ask here but I am curious. I know that many languages will simply explode and fail when asked to divide by 0, but are there any programming languages that can intelligently handle this impossible sum - and if so, what do they do? Do they keep processing, treating 350/0 as 350, or stop execution, or what?

Comment: Are you asking about languages or language implementations?  Not all languages prescribe the exact behavior, and therefore it varies by implementation.

Comment: Asking about how each different language may treat the scenario. Some fascinating answers I've been getting, just curious as to what each language does.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while it is a fun question, it's not a great fit for Stack Overflow.  The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) states, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  This feels like it falls squarely in this category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Infinities):

*The infinities of the extended real number line can be represented in IEEE floating point datatypes, just like ordinary floating point values like 1, 1.5 etc. They are not error values in any way, though they are often (but not always, as it depends on the rounding) used as replacement values when there is an overflow. Upon a divide by zero exception, a positive or negative infinity is returned as an exact result.*

Answer (score 4):

The little-known [Java programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) gives the special constant `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` (depending on the numerator) when you divide by zero in an IEEE floating-point context. Integer division by zero is undefined, and results in an `ArithmeticException` being thrown, which is quite different from your scenario of "explosion and failure".

Comment: How do you double infinity? Doesn't that just give you infinity? Moronic minds want to know!

Comment: Also, if you double not-a-number, does that make it a number?

Comment: @T.E.D Actually, some infinities are bigger than others because of the rate at which they are expanding, eg. SUM(1..n) is a smaller infinity than SUM(1^2...n^2), as n approaches infinity (it's to do with limits in mathematics)

Answer (score 3):

The [INTERCAL](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal-man/home.html) standard library returns `#0` on divide by zero

Answer (score 1):

In Java, division by zero in a floating-point context produces the special value [`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: or `Double.NaN`, if you divide zero by zero.

Answer (score 0):

i'd be surprised if any language returns 350 if you do 350/0. Just two examples, but Java throws an Exception that can be caught. C/C++ just crashes (i think it throws a Signal that can probably be caught).

Comment: There are two distinct languages called C and C++, and I don't think either of them has any specific provision in their standards.  Some implementations of one or both languages may well throw signals.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi, it either throw a compile-time error (if divided by a 0 value const) or a catchable runtime error if it happens at runtime.

It's the same for C and C++.

In PHP you will get a warning:

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   *<file.php>* on line *X*

So, in PHP, for something like:

```
$i = 123 / 0;
```

$i will be set to nothing. **BUT** $i is not === NULL and isset($i) returns true and is_string($i) returns false.

Comment: if you only get a warning, what does the expression return?

Comment: Updated answer with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Python (at least version 2, I don't have 3) throws a ZeroDivisionError, which can be caught.

```
num = 42
try:
    for divisor in (1,0):
        ans = num / divisor
        print ans
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "Trying to divide by 0!"
```

prints out:

```
42
Trying to divide by 0!
```

Comment: Version 3.1 still raises a ZeroDivisionError.

Answer (score 0):

[Most SQL implementations raise a "division by zero" error, but MySQL just returns NULL](http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html#1_11)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers as per the IEEE define constants NaN etc. Any continued operation involving thst value will remain unchanged until the end. Integer or whole numbers are different with exceptions being thrown...In java...

Answer (score 0):

In pony division by 0 is 0 but i have yet to find a language where 0/0 is 1

Answer (score -2):

I'm working with polyhedra and trying to choose a language that likes inf. 
The total edges for a polyhedron {a,b} where a is edges per polygon and b is edges per corner is
E = 1/(1/a + 1/b - 1/2)

if E is negative it's a negative curvature, but if E is infinity (1/0) it tiles the plane.  Examples:  {3,6}   {4,4}

Comment: Could you please give us a hint how this answers the OP's question?

Comment: It's an example of a use of infinity. I guess I commented on the wrong thread.

Comment: @RobertHayes Welcome to SO! This is a Q&A library, not a forum. There are no threads and answers aren't comments. You might want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)