# scanf doesn't take all in inputs

Tags: c, scanf

I supposed to perform a project which allocate N bytes of memory of struct person
and scanning f every person's name initial_money and some other variables
the problem for me when i run the code is that it is terminating at some point of taking input process and i don't why 
also this problem faced me yesterday in code forces contest

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person
{
    char name[15];
    int initial_money;
    int g;
    int final_money;
    int money;

};

int main()
{

    int NP,i,j;
    char target1[15];
    scanf("%d",&NP);
    struct person *p=malloc(NP*sizeof(struct person));
    for(i=0;i<NP;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",(p+i)->name);
    }
    for(i=0;i<NP;i++)
    {

        scanf("%s",target1);

        for(j=0;j<NP;j++)
        {
            if((p+j)->name==target1)
            {
                scanf("%d%d",(p+j)->initial_money,(p+j)->g);
                (p+j)->final_money=(p+j)->initial_money%(p+j)->g;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<NP;i++)
    {

        printf("%s %d %d %d",(p+i)->name,(p+i)->initial_money,(p+i)->g,(p+i)->final_money);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(p+j)->name==target1` is wrong! you need strcmp

Comment: your question is not objective their are multiple mistakes (both logical and technical) I would suggest you to pick a good book and read that. Before to use any operator and function you must read about that. logically you want to compare strings but you are comparing address.

Comment: it should be `if(!strcmp((p+j)->name, target1))`

Comment: Yes. Use strcmp like that . When you use ==, you compare pointers,i.e, whether both strings are stored in the same memory location(which will never be true) rather than comparing the content of both the strings.

Comment: can you suggest  to me a good reference  ?

Comment: @OmarKhaled [**Yes**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: is there any problem in mod by 0 N%0 it shows me error too ! @Grijesh chauhan

Comment: @OmarKhaled `N % 0` is a [divide by zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388842/how-different-programming-languages-handle-division-by-0) problem

Comment: Your subject line says "... doesn't not ...". If you meant "doesn't", I suggest you edit it to remove the "not".

Answer (score 2):

The scanf function need pointers for inputed values.
The line:

```
scanf("%d%d",(p+j)->initial_money,(p+j)->g);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%d %d",&(p+j)->initial_money,&(p+j)->g);
```

When comparing strings you usually can't compare pointers directly:

```
 if((p+j)->name==target1)
```

shoul be:

```
 if(strcmp((p+j)->name, target1) == 0)
```

Comment: (p+j) points somewhere ok, but when it is followed by `->`, the pointer is dereferenced and it is no more a pointer.