# Why does Math.log(0) return -Infinity in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, infinity

When my `Math.log` value getting zero it is giving `-Infinity` value. Why it is giving negative Infinity value? Why only giving -Infinity rather giving +Infinity. Why only 0 value is giving this result.

```js
console.log(Math.log(0))
```

Comment: And what value do you expect?

Comment: expecting any number or error for handling

Comment: Because that's how the specification says it has to work: [20.2.2.20 `Math.log( x )`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.log): _"If x is +0 or −0, the result is −∞."_

Comment: `-Inf` is the most suitable answer because `exp(-Inf )=0` in mathematics - it is not true for "any number"

Comment: Will it give always negative or it can give positive value too.

Comment: The question doesn't deserve downvotes. It is good to know that neither `Math.log(0)` nor `x/0` will throw exception in javascript, which doesn't necessarily make consensus among other languages.[divisionByZero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388842/how-different-programming-languages-handle-division-by-0). This choice seems motivated by the fact that javascript is interpreted language

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, because [that's how it's specified](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-math.log):

> 20.2.2.20 `Math.log ( x )`
>
> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the natural logarithm of x.
>
> - If x is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - If x is less than 0, the result is NaN.
> - **If x is +0 or -0, the result is -∞.**
> - If x is 1, the result is +0.
> - If x is +∞, the result is +∞.

*(my emphasis)*

But more to the point, `log(x)` as `x` approaches `0` [decreases without bound](http://www.analyzemath.com/logfunction/logfunction.html). So -Infinity seems a reasonable choice for the spec to make.

Answer (score -2):

**Because log 0 is undefined and so they've implemented it that way.**

> console.log(Infinity);           /* Infinity */
>
> console.log(Infinity + 1);         /* Infinity */
>
> console.log(Math.pow(10, 1000));   /* Infinity*/
>
> console.log(Math.log(0));          /* -Infinity */
>
> console.log(1 / Infinity);        /* 0 */

Specs: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity#Beispiele